# FFmpeg, how to skip late input?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm running ffmpeg to display incoming stream on a Decklink BlackMagic card with the following command line:

```
ffmpeg -y -f ourFmt -probesize 32 -i - -f decklink -preset ultrafast 
   -pix_fmt uyvy422 -s 1920x1080 -r 30 -af volume=0.1 -max_delay 10000 
     DeckLink Mini Monitor
```

Basically I get the video over the internet by UDP and stream it to ffmpeg stdin. Both audio and video streams have pts and dts and are fully in sync, if the connection is good there is no problems.

However if there are issues with the connection i start getting errors, sometimes the video delay grows significantly, and audio stops working.
The errors i get are:

> ffmpeg: [decklink @ 0x26cc600] There are not enough buffered video
>   frames. Video may misbehave! ffmpeg: [decklink @ 0x26cc600] There's no
>   buffered audio. Audio will misbehave! ffmpeg:     Last message
>   repeated 4 times ffmpeg: [decklink @ 0x26cc600] There are not enough
>   buffered video frames. Video may misbehave! ffmpeg: [decklink @
>   0x26cc600] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave! ffmpeg:
>   Last message repeated 3 times ffmpeg: frame= 5204 fps= 30 q=-0.0
>   size=N/A time=00:02:53.76 bitrate=N/A dup=385 drop=5 speed=0.993x
>   ffmpeg: [decklink @ 0x26cc600] There's no buffered audio. Audio will
>   misbehave! ffmpeg:     Last message repeated 18 times ffmpeg:
>   [decklink @ 0x26cc600] There are not enough buffered video frames.
>   Video may misbehave! ffmpeg: [decklink @ 0x26cc600] There's no
>   buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!

The problem is when the connection is back to normal, the video keeps misbehaving until I restart the stream. What I want to do is for FFmpeg to skip to the content of the last second and play synchronized video from there, drop all the late data in between, is it possible?

Comment: Did you try `-itsoffset` parameter ?

Comment: That would just delay the whole stream from what I understand from the documentation. I need ffmpeg to be able to recover from insufficient input, thus minimize the display delay, not add to it.

Comment: Have you tried `-async 1 -vsync -1` ?